# Should I load all data into an array and filter it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, filtering

I'm working with punk beer API https://punkapi.com/documentation/v2 to build an app that can search and filter beers by ABV. I want to divide all beers in the API into 3 categories: weak (0-5%), medium (5%-12%), and strong (>12%).

At first, I was thinking of making an API call for each range using the parameters abv_lt and abv_gt that the doc provides. But then I think it'd be expensive to make an API call each time the user clicks on a criteria.

So my next approach is to just load all beers into a big array by joining all pages together and do all the filtering and searching from the local master array (each request only returns 25 beers by default) :

```
getAllBeers(){
  const requestURL=`${root_api}beers`;
   axios.all([
      axios.get(`${requestURL}?page=1&per_page=80`),
      axios.get(`${requestURL}?page=2&per_page=80`),
      axios.get(`${requestURL}?page=3&per_page=80`),
    ])
     .then(axios.spread(function (data1, data2,data3) {
      let beerData1 = data1.data;
      let beerData2 = data2.data;
      let beerData3 = data3.data;
      let master_data = beerData1.concat(beerData2, beerData3);
      return master_data;
     }))
}
```

I would appreciate if there's a better or effective approach on this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The best approach is probably to fit your front-end to the way the API provides the data. Currently you are likely to fetch way more data in advance then most users will ever look at. This puts unnecessary load on the server and wastes bandwidth of the client. The computational power needed for sorting an array is neglectable for modern device as long as the list is not huge.

So it may be best to just fetch the first page of unfiltered beer and initially display that to the user. Only fetch more if the user actually wants to apply a filter or see the next page.

Also many APIs support caching results and tell your client that it already has up-to-date data when repeating the same request. This works best if you tell the API which data you actually want to have.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific please?

Comment: @ChuChu What is not clear enough to you? I can elaborate on that.